# How to access a previous value from a two way binded form input control?

Tags: javascript, sql, angular, typescript, two-way-binding

Given the form here, I would like to be able to Update data in a SQL Table.  In order to create the SQL query needed to make this happen I'll have to pass in both the previous row's value and the new row's value to make the proper comparison.

*Example SQL Update Statement:*

```
UPDATE MyTable 
SET column1 = new_value1, column2 = new_value2, 
WHERE column1 = oldValue1 AND column2 = oldValue2
```

Since my input is using two way binding however, I always get the new value when trying to pass it to my SQL service.  Is there a way to access the row's previous value prior to sending it for update?

*Form HTML:*

```
  <form #updateRowForm="ngForm" class="update-row-form">
            <table mdbTable #tableEl="mdbTable" class="table table-bordered
              table-responsive-md table-striped text-center">
              <thead>
                <tr>
                  <th *ngFor="let head of loadedTableData[0] | keys;">{{head}}</th>
                </tr>
              </thead>
              <tbody>
                <tr *ngFor="let item of loadedTableData; let i = index;">
                  <td *ngFor="let property of item | keys;"
                    class="form-group" #editRow>
                    <input #editRowProp mdbInput
                      [(ngModel)]="loadedTableData[i][property]"
                      (click)="updateValue(item)"
                      (ngModelChange)="changeValue($event, item)"
                      class="form-control"
                      [name]="property + '_' + i"
                      type="text">
                  </td>
                  <td>
                    <button type="button" mdbBtn class="btn btn-primary
                      rounded
                      btn-sm my-0"
                      (click)="updateRow(loadedTableData[i], item)">Update</button>
                    <hr>
                    <button type="button" mdbBtn class="btn btn-danger
                      rounded
                      btn-sm my-0" (click)="deleteRow(item)">Remove</button>
                  </td>
                </tr>
              </tbody>
            </table>
          </form>
```

*Component TS file:*

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild, ViewChildren, QueryList, OnDestroy } from 
'@angular/core';
import { SqlService } from '../services/sql.service';
import { MdbTablePaginationComponent, MdbTableDirective } from 'angular-bootstrap-md';
import { NgForm, FormGroup } from '@angular/forms';
import { Subscription, BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs';
import { MatSnackBar } from '@angular/material';
import { SuccessComponent } from '../snackbar/success/success.component';
import { ErrorComponent } from '../snackbar/error/error.component';
import { ConfirmComponent } from '../snackbar/confirm/confirm.component';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-data-table',
  templateUrl: './data-table.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./data-table.component.scss']
})
export class DataTableComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  @ViewChild(MdbTablePaginationComponent) mdbTablePagination: 
  MdbTablePaginationComponent;
  @ViewChild(MdbTableDirective) mdbTable: MdbTableDirective;
  @ViewChild('addRowForm') addRowForm: NgForm;
  @ViewChildren('prop') addRowProps: QueryList<any>;
  @ViewChild('editRowForm') editRowForm: NgForm;
  @ViewChild('editRow') editRow: FormGroup;

  public loadedTableData: any = [];
  public previousTableData: any = [];
  public displayedColumns: any = [];
  public tableHasBeenLoaded = false;
  public rowBeingEdited: BehaviorSubject<any> = new BehaviorSubject<any>({});
  public rowPreviousValue: BehaviorSubject<any> = new BehaviorSubject<any>({});
  public currentTableData: any = {};
  public rowsAffected = 0;

  public elements: string[] = [];
  public previous: any;

  private subscriptions: Subscription[] = [];

  constructor(private sqlService: SqlService,
              private snackBar: MatSnackBar) { }

  public ngOnInit(): void {
    this.subscriptions.push(
      this.sqlService.tableHasBeenLoaded.subscribe(data => {
        this.tableHasBeenLoaded = data;
      }),

  this.sqlService.tableHasBeenLoaded.subscribe(data => {
       this.tableHasBeenLoaded = data;
  }),

  this.sqlService.currentTableData.subscribe(data => {
    this.currentTableData = data;
  }),

  this.sqlService.rowsAffected.subscribe(data => {
    this.rowsAffected = data;
      })
    );
  }

  public updateRow(newRowValue: any, previousRowValue: any): void {

    // Both of these values are the same.
    console.log(newRowValue, ' << initialRow');
    console.log(previousRowValue, ' <<previousRowVal')



    const updateData = {
      previousRowValue,
      newRowValue
    };

    this.subscriptions.push(
      this.sqlService.updateTableData(updateData)
        .subscribe((resp) => {
        console.log(resp, ' << update response');
        // this.sqlService.currentDataView.next(resp);
        if (resp) {
          this.snackBar.openFromComponent(ConfirmComponent, {
            duration: 3000,
            data: this.rowsAffected
          });
        }
      })
     );

  }

  public ngOnDestroy(): void {
    for (const sub of this.subscriptions) {
      sub.unsubscribe();
    }
  }

}
```

*SQL Service TS:*

```
    import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
    import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
    import { tap } from 'rxjs/operators';
    import { Observable, BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs';
    import { ITableList } from '../interfaces/ITableList.interface';

    @Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
    })
    export class SqlService {

    private uri = 'http://localhost:8080';
    private headers = new HttpHeaders({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8' });

    public currentDataView: BehaviorSubject<any> = new BehaviorSubject<any>([]);
    public currentTableData: BehaviorSubject<any> = new BehaviorSubject<any>({});
    public tableHasBeenLoaded: BehaviorSubject<any> = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(false);
    public rowsAffected: BehaviorSubject<number> = new BehaviorSubject<number>(0);

    constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

    public updateTableData(updateData: any): Observable<any> {
        const parsedData = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(updateData));

        if (updateData) {
        return this.http.post(`${this.uri}/api/updateTableData`, parsedData).pipe(
            tap(
            response => {
                this.rowsAffected.next(response.rowsAffected);
            },
            error => {
                throw new Error(error);
            }
            )
        );
        }
    }

  }
```

Comment: I'm confused...why do you need the previous value? Shouldn't the new data just replace the previous data?

Comment: @Viqas For SQL statements, an Update action requires a condition, in my case,  I would need to compare the row's previous value ( so that I can reference it in the database ) to the new value.   Eg )   
UPDATE MyTable
SET 
    column1 = new_value1,
    column2 = new_value2,
    ...
WHERE
    column1 = oldValue1; AND column2 = oldValue2;

Comment: Couldn't you just use the primary key (an `id` maybe) to reference the record you want to update. That's how you should be doing it.

Comment: @Viqas I see what you're saying, but given my SQL table with 2 columns , Column A is a 2 char input and Column B is a 45 varchar description,  I don't believe I have access to a UUID unless there is one built in to SQL server that I am not aware of?  ( I am still new to SQL & SQL Server )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

hi create one more object(e.g prevValue) store value in it.that should be deepcopy not shallow copy.. use JSON.stringify and JSON.parse to copy value in object.
e.g In newValue object you store the new value, before assigning the new  value, save newValue in prevValue, by this you will have prevValue, 
like if you want first value than don't update preValue

Comment: Thank you sir!  That is what I needed to do.  By creating a deep copy, I could store both the old value and the new value to send to my SQL server for an Update comparison.